# How to separate a line into two after ":" by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a blog and blog titles are like this;

"Hey There: Part 1"

So, is there any chance to break the line after ":", because I want Part 1 to start a new line. So it should be like this:

"Hey there:

Part 1"

But there are so many titles, so I want to do this with a javascript code to all of those titles. Is this possible?

Comment: `string.split(':').join('\n or <br>')` or `string.replace(/:/g, '\n or <br>')`

Comment: Amusing that the best answer is in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split()` of JavaScript

```
var text = "Hey There : Part 1";
var newText = text.split(":").join('\n');
alert(newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var blogTitle = $('theTitleElement')
$(blogTitle).each(function(){
   $(this).html(this.textContent.split(':').join('<br>'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`%0D%0A` are the characters for a carriage return and line break if you're URL encoding.

`%0D` is a carriage return character `%0A` is a line break character.

If you want to line break in your JavaScript code then you can use `\n` to escape a line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sOrig = "Hey There: Part 1";
sOrig.split(':').join('\n');
```

you can replace the `\n` with html etc if needed or just do a `replace()`